# How to use sqlx to do queries with table fields and parameters?

Tags: go, sqlx

I would like to ask about possible strategies to prepare the status of a query with the following structure:

```
select TABLE_COLUM from TABLE where OTHER_TABLE_COLUMN = {'$ 1 PARAMETER'},
```

The language is Go and the sqlx library.

I am using a function with the following structure:

```
type Translation struct {
    Translation string
}
```

```
type TranslateParams struct {
    Originlanguaje string 
    Wordtotranslate string
    Targetlanguaje string 
}
```

```
//TranslateWordUsingDB... TranslateWordUsingDB search one word translation in DB
func ObtainTranslationUsingDB(validationforuse bool,originlang string, word string, targetlang string)([]Translation, error){
    translation := []Translation{}
    if validationforuse == true{
        fmt.Println("preparing....")
        params := TranslateParams{
            Originlanguaje  : originlang,
            Wordtotranslate : word,
            Targetlanguaje  : targetlang,
        }
        nstmt, err := db.Conn.PrepareNamed(`select :targetlanguaje as translation from translations where :originlanguaje = :wordtotranslate`)
        if err != nil{
            return translation, err
        }
        fmt.Println("prepared")
        error := nstmt.Select(&translation, params)
        if error != nil {
            return translation, error
        }
        fmt.Println(translation)
    }
    return translation, nil
}
```

But this does not work and I have not managed the methods of https://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/#namedParams
because they replace TABLE_COLUMN with "TABLE_COLUMN" and this does not allow the query to work.